# Arbitrary union in lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

So the lower limit topology on R has open sets of the form [a, b), where a<b, so far so good, my question is, if the arbitrary union of left closed sets can be open, that is for example $$\cup_\lambda^{\infty} [1/\lambda, 1)= (0,1)$$, where $\lambda\in N$, how does it fullfil the condition that the arbitrary unions of set in the collection is another set in the collection?

PS: I know this may be a dumb question, but the professor said it was trivial and I can't find a proof for the lower limit topology being a topology.

Comment: The lower limit topology has sets like $[a,b)$ as its **basis**.  That is not the complete list of all open sets.  As you've pointed out, things like $(a,b)$ are also open.

Comment: So that's why! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 100% correct. The collection of subsets of the form $[a,b)$ **is not** closed under arbitrary unions. You've observed correctly that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [\frac{1}{n},1)=(0,1)$ which clearly is not of the form $[a,b)$. Another simple example is $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[0,n)=[0,\infty)$ which again is not of the form $[a,b)$. Another example is $[0,1)\cup[2,3)$ which is not of the form $[a,b)$.

So the collection of all subsets of the form $[a,b)$ is not a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. But that's not how the lower limit topology is defined. In fact it is defined to be the topology **generated by** all subsets of the form $[a,b)$.

So yeah, it is trivial. But nothing is trivial before it becomes trivial. Don't you love when a professor says "it is trivial" without actually explaining anything? :)

Note that the observation you've made has an interesting generalization. It can be shown that every interval of the form $(a,b)$ is open in the lower limit topology. Or equivalently that the lower limit topology contains the standard Euclidean topology.

Comment: Yes, thank you veyr much, I see it now, for some reason professor defined the open sets of lower limit topology as exclusively [a, b) therefore my confusion. From what I heard it's a general rule that topology professors are like what I described, hehe. Thank you again.

Comment: @JocsanArielHernandezBarahon it is quite standard to define a topology by giving a basis for it, as is done here. For many arguments involving continuity, compactness, connectedness etc it suffices to know that basis. The actual topology is larger as you’ve shown.